# How to get a user id from Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

how can I get an ID of a user after that has been created , i am creating the user 
by using createUserWithEmailAndPassword function

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
.then(resp => handleUserCreated(resp.uid, name...))
```

in handleUserCreated function i try to insert into database that user , the problem is that the ID that it gives me = undefined

```
const handleUserCreated  = (userId, name ...) =>
firebase.database().ref(`profles/${userId}`)
```

my rules in database

```
  {
      "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
```

could you help me to solve that issue of undefined ID ?

Comment: try `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
.then(resp => { console.log(resp); handleUserCreated(resp.user.uid, name...) })`

Comment: try firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){})

Comment: thanks #MuruGan  that's solved my problem , it worked thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try the following solution, its working fine.

```
createUser() {

   const { email, password } = this.state;

   firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
   .then(data => {  
      console.log("User ID :- ", data.user.uid);
   })
   .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
   });

}
```

Comment: This works well,but for app logic we need to extract that user.uid outside auth object to be usefull in our app logic and i cant find solution how to do that.I will apreciate any help.Thanks